# Add Help Tip to MS Access form

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to add a "Help" tip to a field in an Access form such that when the user hover's the mouse over the field, the tip shows up in a window and then fades away once the user either selects the field or their mouse is no longer hovering over the field?

This would be similar to a Note in MS Excel.

I could probably manage this using events or just put a help button next to the field, but was thinking there may be some simple solution such as a property I'm not aware of.

I did some google searching and was unable to find anything to accomplish this.

Comment: I found the property I was looking for shortly after posting this.  It's the "ControlTip Text" property available in the "Other" tab of the property sheet.  I'll leave the question anyways as I couldn't find anything about this and maybe someone has some nice slick suggestions too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the form field, under the "Other" property tab you enter your Help Tip in the ControlTip Text field.